# codecov doesn't find any reports

Tags: code-coverage, codecov

I have been stuck with this for the last couple of days.

I created a private github repository with CMake, C++. I then added actions to build and test the code. Since the repo is private, I added a secret token as suggested by the codeconv docs.

After the tests are completed, I wish to also check for code coverage with the codeconv, so I added another another step at the bottom of my YAML:

```
      - name: Test
        working-directory: ${{ steps.strings.outputs.build-output-dir }}
        run: ctest --verbose -C ${{ matrix.build_type }} --reporter xml

      - name: Upload coverage reports to Codecov
        uses: codecov/codecov-action@v4.0.1
        with:
          token: ${{ secrets.CODECOV_TOKEN }}
          slug: <user>/<repo>
```

as was suggested by the codecov docs.

In case that matters, my executables are not in the same directory as build. The tests pass, but the codeconv exits with an error:

```
info - 2024-03-20 09:56:26,137 -- ci service found: github-actions
warning - 2024-03-20 09:56:26,141 -- No config file could be found. Ignoring config.
warning - 2024-03-20 09:56:26,147 -- xcrun is not installed or can't be found.
warning - 2024-03-20 09:56:26,163 -- No gcov data found.
warning - 2024-03-20 09:56:26,164 -- coverage.py is not installed or can't be found.
info - 2024-03-20 09:56:26,196 -- Found 0 coverage files to upload
Error: No coverage reports found. Please make sure you're generating reports successfully.
Warning: Codecov: 
                      Failed to properly upload report: The process '/home/runner/work/_actions/codecov/codecov-action/v4.0.1/dist/codecov' failed with exit code 1
```

complaining that the report was not found. Does anybody have an idea what to do?